# Document Library add file with custom column (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: document-library, column

I have a document library with a custom column. I want to add a file programatically, as well as a value for the custom column. I am posting the file via an ASP.NET application page. Here is what I have:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["MyFile"];
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPFolder library = web.Folders["MyLibrary"];
SPFile spFile = library.Files.Add(file.FileName, file.InputStream);
/* The next two lines are an attempt to add the custom column value */
spFile.Item["CustomColumn"] = "CustomColumnValue";
spFile.Update();
library.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

It does add the file to the document library, but it does not add the value for the custom column. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was going wrong.

Instead of:

```
spFile.Item["CustomColumn"] = "CustomColumnValue";
spFile.Update();
```

do this:

```
spFile.Item.Properties["CustomColumn"] = "CustomColumnValue";
spFile.Item.SystemUpdate();
spFile.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
spfile.Item["Title"] = "Workk";
spfile.Item.Update();
spfile.Update();
```

Comment: ... for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right, this is another solution using a hashtable variable:
you can upload the file from a SPFolder or SPWeb as following:

```
// Add custom value to the column library
System.Collections.Hashtable properties = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
properties.Add("My custom column name", "My value");

web.Files.Add("CustomFolder/" + name + ".txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), properties);
```

And the file will be uploaded with the value you set on the custom column.

I know is kind of late, but maybe it would be useful for someone else.

Regards